# How to get every single day of the current month in a specific format

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I would like to output all days of the current month at once. The format (e.g. for August) should be `Monday - 01.08.22` to `Wednesday - 31.08.22`. I would like to transfer each individual day into an Excel list. My question is how I can output the individual days of the current month programmatically.

I can imagine using the library `DateTime moment = new DateTime();`

Comment: I expect a lack of demonstrated effort (research or attempt) to solve this by yourself.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I have done that, however I have considered not publishing my buggy code. Thanks anyway for the criticism, I will use it to improve myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be simple enough to do with the help of `DateTime.DaysInMonth`.

First we'll use the starting `DateTime` to get the year and month number to create a new `DateTime` for the first day of the month.

Next we'll get the number of days in the month.

We'll then loop from 0 to [daysInMonth] (exclusive) adding that number of days to the startOfMonth date.

Finally, for each we can convert it to a string in the desired format.

```cs
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 1);
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(startTime.Year, startTime.Month);
for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; ++i)
{
    DateTime currentDate = startOfMonth.AddDays(i);
    Console.WriteLine(currentDate.ToString("dddd - dd.MM.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/PFP45089)

Output for today:

```
Monday - 01.08.22
Tuesday - 02.08.22
Wednesday - 03.08.22
Thursday - 04.08.22
Friday - 05.08.22
Saturday - 06.08.22
Sunday - 07.08.22
Monday - 08.08.22
Tuesday - 09.08.22
Wednesday - 10.08.22
Thursday - 11.08.22
Friday - 12.08.22
Saturday - 13.08.22
Sunday - 14.08.22
Monday - 15.08.22
Tuesday - 16.08.22
Wednesday - 17.08.22
Thursday - 18.08.22
Friday - 19.08.22
Saturday - 20.08.22
Sunday - 21.08.22
Monday - 22.08.22
Tuesday - 23.08.22
Wednesday - 24.08.22
Thursday - 25.08.22
Friday - 26.08.22
Saturday - 27.08.22
Sunday - 28.08.22
Monday - 29.08.22
Tuesday - 30.08.22
Wednesday - 31.08.22
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<string> GetMonthDays(int month)
{
    var year = DateTime.Now.Year;

    return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
        .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month,day).ToString("dddd - dd.MM.yy"))
        .ToList();
}
```

*call*

```
var days = GetMonthDays(8);

foreach(var day in days)
{
   Console.WriteLine(day);
}
```

*output*

Monday - 01.08.22

Tuesday - 02.08.22

...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the root cause of your problem, but in order to calculate the end date of a month (in other words, what's the amount of days), you might do the following (pseudo-code):

```
DateTime nextMonth = new DateTime(1, month + 1, 2022) - 1;
```

(Just take the first day of the next month and subtract 1)

In case you're dealing with the month December, you might do the following:

```
DateTime nextMonth = month == 12 ? 
                       new DateTime(1, 1, 2023) - 1 : 
                       new DateTime(1, month + 1, 2022) - 1;
```

Comment: This will not work in December ;-)

Comment: @KlausGütter: thanks for the remark, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`instead of simply `1`?

Comment: @KlausGütter: that's possible. Hence "pseudo-code" :-)